# How to remove rows from a data frame when the column matches with a different data frame column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame A of the below format

`Word     Freq
p        9531
can      2085
/p       2055
get      1183
use      1112`

and another data frame B

`Word     Freq
p        10
can      2
/p       55`

Now I want to remove the rows from data frame A that has a matching in the data frame B.
So my output would be for data frame A

`Word     Freq
get      1183
use      1112`

Comment: `A[!(A$Word %in% B$Word),]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
A<-read.table(text="Word     Freq
p        9531
can      2085
/p       2055
get      1183
use      1112",header=T)

B<-read.table(text="Word     Freq
p        10
can      2
/p       55",header=T)

A[-which(A$Word %in% B$Word),]
```

result:

```
  Word Freq
4  get 1183
5  use 1112
```